# How can we implement web sockets in a google chrome extention

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

--i am getting this error: Permission 'webSocket' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

1.in manifest.json : `"permissions": \["webRequest", "storage", "cookies", "webSocket"\],`

2.in background.js :

```
var socket = new WebSocket(
"wss://example.com"
);
socket.onopen = function () {
console.log("WebSocket connection established.");
};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
console.log("Received message:", event.data);
};

socket.onclose = function (event) {
console.log(
"WebSocket connection closed with code:",
event.code,
"reason:",
event.reason
);
};
socket.send("Hello, server!");
```

can anyone help me with the code ?

Comment: Did ChatGPT write the code?

Comment: There's no such permission for extensions.